# SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host [host]: getaddrinfo: No such host is known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, vps

I've been trying to deploy my app to a vps and got this error  !The deploy has failed with an error: #

here is my deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'appname'
set :repo_url, 'https://someone@bitbucket.org/'
set :branch, 'master'
set :scm, :git
set :deploy_to, '/home/dir'

set :deploy_via, :remote_catche

set :user, "user"
set :scm_username, "username"
set :use_sudo, false

#default_run_options[:pty] = true tried uncomenting this and it threw me an error 

# Default value for :scm is :git


# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
# set :log_level, :debug


 namespace :deploy do
 desc "Restart nginx"
 task :restart do
 run "#{deploy_to}/bin/restart"
 end
 end
```

And here is my production.rb

```
role :app, %w{web334.webfaction.com‏}
role :web, %w{web334.webfaction.com‏}
role :db,  %w{postgres}
```

What can i do to deploy this app succesfuly, help

Answer (score 0):

In `production.rb` file this `role :db,  %w{postgres}` looks wrong. With this, capistrano will use `postgres` as a database server url, and that naturally fails.

Why don't you have server url or ip instead of `postgres`? I suppose it should be this:

```
role :db, %w{web334.webfaction.com‏}
```

If your app doesn't have a database, feel free to remove the `db` role.

Comment: it still gives me this error, SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host web334.webfactio
n.com?: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.